# IMAP get sender name and body text?

Tags: python, email, imap

I am using this code:

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(myusername, mypassword)
mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0] # data is a list.
id_list = ids.split() # ids is a space separated string
latest_email_id = id_list[-1] # get the latest

result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)") # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID

raw_email = data[0][1] # here's the body, which is raw text of the whole email
# including headers and alternate payloads

print raw_email
```

and it works, except, when I print `raw_email` it returns a bunch of extra information, how can I, parse, per say, the extra information and get just the From and body text?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Python's [email](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email) package is probably a good place to start.

```
import email
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

print msg['From']
print msg.get_payload(decode=True)
```

That should do ask you ask, though when an email has multiple parts (attachments, text and HTML versions of the body, etc.) things are a bit more complicated.

In that case, `msg.is_multipart()` will return True and `msg.get_payload()` will return a list instead of a string. There's a lot more information in the [email.message](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html) documentation.

Alternately, rather than parsing the raw RFC822-formatted message - which could be very large, if the email contains attachments - you could just ask the IMAP server for the information you want. Changing your `mail.fetch` line to:

```
mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)])")
```

Would just request (and return) the *From* line of the email from the server. Likewise setting the second parameter to `"(UID BODY[TEXT])"`  would return the body of the email. [RFC2060](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2060.txt) has a list of parameters that should be valid here.

Answer (score 12):

IMAP high level lib: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools (I am author)

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(all=True)):
        sender = msg.from_
        body = msg.text or msg.html
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The APIs of `imaplib` and Python's `email` package are driving my crazy, and this is SO MUCH BETTER!

Comment: @xjcl, enjoy =D

Comment: If you are advertising your own code, you need to be explicit about it. See our [promotion policy.](/help/promotion)

Comment: really cool lib,

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [Red Box](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/) (I'm the author):

```
from redbox import EmailBox

# Create email box instance
box = EmailBox(
    host="imap.example.com", 
    port=993,
    username="me@example.com",
    password="<PASSWORD>"
)

# Select an email folder
inbox = box["INBOX"]

# Search and process messages
for msg in inbox.search(all=True):

    # Process the message
    print(msg.from_)
    print(msg.to)
    print(msg.subject)
    print(msg.text_body)
    print(msg.html_body)
```

Some relevant links in the documentations:

- [More about querying](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/querying.html)
- [More about manipulating the message](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/message.html)
- [More about configuring the email box](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/config.html)

To install:

```
pip install redbox
```

Links:

- [Source code](https://github.com/Miksus/red-box)
- [Documentation](https://red-box.readthedocs.io/)