# python 3.5 imaplib read gmails as plain text

Tags: python-3.x, imaplib

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
username = 'MyGmail@gmail.com'
password = 'MyPasswordHere'
mail.login(username, password)    
mail.select('INBOX')

typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print(data)
    exit()
```

**This is a part of the whole output:** (not very readable)

[(b'1 (BODY[1] {1115}', b'\r\nHej Bjango For at sikre, at Bjangos side hj=C3=A6lper dig med at n=C3=A5 =\r\ndine m=C3=A5l, giver vi dig her nogle hurtige og nemme forslag til, hvad =\r\ndu kan g=C3=B8re:  Opdater dit profilbillede og dit coverbillede =\r\nOverf=C3=B8r=C2=A0billede Tilf=C3=B8j en beskrivelse af din side =\r\nTilf=C3=B8j=C2=A0en=C2=A0beskrivelse Medtag et link til dit website =\r\nTilf=C3=B8j=C2=A0et=C2=A0link Sl=C3=A5 en opdatering eller et billede op =\r\np=C3=A5 din side Opret=C2=A0et=C2=A0opslag Inviter dine venner til at =\r\nsynes godt om din side Inviter=C2=A0dine=C2=A0venner\r\n\r\nHilsen Facebook-teamet\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=\r\n=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D\r\nDenne besked blev sendt til infobjango@gmail.com. Hvis du ikke =C3=B8nsker =\r\nat modtage disse e-mails fra Facebook fremover, skal du f=C3=B8lge =\r\nnedenst=C3=A5ende link for at afmelde dem.\r\nhttps://www.facebook.com/o.php?k=3DAS38jnuCT_H5AdZt&u=3D100015358233656&mi=\r\nd=3D548339b6125b3G5af6a3e64c38G0G37b\r\nFacebook, Inc., Attention: Community Support, 1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, CA =\r\n94025\r\n\r\n'), b')']

**So here is my question**
How do I make the main part of the mail I received readable?

---

**An example of what I mean by readable:**

Dear bjango

This is a mail, which is totally readable without any `"<<td style=3D"font-size: 16px; =\r\npadding-bottom: 26px; text-ali>"`. That's funny I just made a part of this mail unreadable that was supposed to be readable - I hope you get the point.

Best Regards Bjango

**This approach does not completely solve my issue with readability:**

```
    import email
msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
print(msg.get_payload(decode=False))
```

*Output will be as followed:*

```
Hej Bjango For at sikre, at Bjangos side hj=C3=A6lper dig med at n=C3=A5 =
dine m=C3=A5l, giver vi dig her nogle hurtige og nemme forslag til, hvad =
du kan g=C3=B8re:  Opdater dit profilbillede og dit coverbillede =
Overf=C3=B8r=C2=A0billede Tilf=C3=B8j en beskrivelse af din side =
Tilf=C3=B8j=C2=A0en=C2=A0beskrivelse Medtag et link til dit website =
Tilf=C3=B8j=C2=A0et=C2=A0link Sl=C3=A5 en opdatering eller et billede op =
p=C3=A5 din side Opret=C2=A0et=C2=A0opslag Inviter dine venner til at =
synes godt om din side Inviter=C2=A0dine=C2=A0venner

Hilsen Facebook-teamet
```

- But none the less, it's a massive improvement

**This is the email I intend to get in the output section:**

Hej Bjango For at sikre, at Bjangos side hjælper dig med at nå
dine mål, giver vi dig her nogle hurtige og nemme forslag til, hvad 
du kan gøre:  Opdater dit profilbillede og dit coverbillede 
Overfører billeder Tilføj en beskrivelse af din side 
Tilføj en beskrivelse Medtag et link til dit website 
Tilføj et link Slå en opdatering eller et billede op 
på din side Opret et opslag Inviter dine venner til at 
synes godt om din side Inviter dine venner

Hilsen Facebook-teamet

Comment: Could you specify a little more what you mean by readable? Can you describe specifically what is the desired output / outcome? Also have you taken a look into imaplib's example code: https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example Is that sufficiently readable or do you need something more specific?

Comment: That was the example code that I used ^ Also I updated my question

Comment: Your code isn't identical: the example prints out `data[0][1]`. Would that be sufficiently readable? Do you mean that you would only want to print out body of the email?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IMAP get sender name and body text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540192/imap-get-sender-name-and-body-text)

Comment: @jsalonen that is old from 2013 python2, wich does not work. I have alread tried

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Which version? Please flag that to your question as well

Comment: It's in the headline, but i'll ad it too as a tag. You can also see that I am using python 3, because of the fact that I use "print('something')" in my code.

Comment: I use python 3.5 - but that shouldn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 [email parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_bytes) should work here:

```
import email
msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
payload = msg.get_payload(decode=True)
```

Assuming your email is encoded as MIME quoted-printable data, you can proceed to decode that using [quopri module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html):

```
import quopri
message = quopri.decodestring(payload).decode('utf-8')

print(message)
```

Comment: That was the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540192/imap-get-sender-name-and-body-text
Which didn't work for me. I have already tried that. It didn't change anything. You could try yourself? with the input from my question - remember to use python3

Comment: @Bjango I have verified the above code works for Python 3. Please look at the code more closely. I'm using `message_from_bytes`, not `message_from_string`, since Python 3 handles those messages as bytes not as strings.

Comment: I am so sorry, it missed that detail. You are right it works. Not completely as I intended though.

Comment: @Bjango What do you intend then? I'm happy to elaborate if you tell me more specifically what you are looking for.

Comment: I have updated my question with the email I intend to get

Comment: @Bjango Updated the answer

Comment: YES, thank you very much sir that was the exact answer I was looking for.